Is there a word or idiom that describes an object which covertly harms or obstructs its user?
What would be a fitting word to describe objects designed to purposefully obstruct, mislead or harm anyone that uses it without them knowing. One working example could be a treasure-seeker who receives a tampered compass and falsified map - all with the intention of them getting lost or shipwrecked by using it.
Keep in mind this is different from term trap street which are falsified cartography entries designed to catch plagiarists. Also, Jury Rigged would not work either, the word must describe something intentional and covert.

Since sabotage means
'deliberately destroy, damage, or obstruct (something), especially for
political or military advantage'
[[ODE courtesy of Google]
and you ask for an adjective, sabotaged  is a hypernym. But there is no requirement that the damage be covert, so not submitted as an 'answer'.

A wrecker intentionally causes harm. The dictionaries do not support this meaning – but in Cornwall UK, wreckers apparently used false lights to lure ships on to the rocks so that they could be plundered. Whether or not the story is myth, that word is used. See The False Lights of Britain.

Do you mean to say that jury rigged would not work because its purpose is not to covertly harm? Seems like you left out not there....

@TinfoilHat yes thats a typo.

Your own tampered (adj.), tamper with (v.) is good.

@EdwinAshworth I think you are being too strict about sabotage. The OED definition includes "... esp. that carried out clandestinely in order to disrupt the economic or military resources of an enemy. " in the definition.

@Cody To jury rig is, in fact, close to an antonym; it means to get something (often broken or damaged) to work by makeshift means--not to tamper, trick, or prevent from working.

@DjinTonic good to know!

If you're looking for an adjective, I'd suggest insidious.

@DjinTonic With sabotage, the undertaking is always clandestine, but the 'harming the target without them knowing' is often inappropriate.

You could call such an object a Trojan Horse. Collins gives the following definition:

If you describe a person or thing as a Trojan horse, you mean that they are being used to hide someone's true purpose or intentions. [disapproval]

They claim he is a Trojan horse being used by the party bosses attempting to steal the nomination.
Merriam-Webster has this bit of information about the literal Trojan horse, which is now mostly used figuratively.

After besieging the walls of Troy for ten years, the Greeks built a huge, hollow wooden horse, secretly filled it with armed warriors, and presented it to the Trojans as a gift for the goddess Athena, and the Trojans took the horse inside the city's walls. That night, the armed Greeks swarmed out and captured and burned the city. A Trojan horse is thus anything that looks innocent but, once accepted, has power to harm or destroy—for example, a computer program that seems helpful but ends up corrupting or demolishing the computer's software.


This object could be called a booby trap (noun) or described as booby-trapped (adjective).

booby trap noun
1. A means of deliberately tricking or luring an unwary or foolish person into difficulty or error. Also: a hidden or unsuspected source
of difficulty; a pitfall....
booby-trapped adjective
2. That has or includes hidden or unexpected difficulties or pitfalls; designed or intended to trick or lure an unwary or foolish
person into difficulty or error. Cf. booby trap n. 1.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)


The belief in this as an innate property of things is resistentialism. Somebody let a feral object loose. As a mechanic and engineer, I have been gamekeeper of a resistential menagerie for 40 years.

Resistentialism is a jocular theory to describe "seemingly spiteful behavior manifested by inanimate objects",[1] where objects that cause problems (like lost keys, printers, or a runaway bouncy ball) are said to exhibit a high degree of malice toward humans. The theory posits a war being fought between humans and inanimate objects, and all the little annoyances that objects cause throughout the day are battles between the two. The concept was not new in 1948 when humorist Paul Jennings coined this name for it in a piece titled "Report on Resistentialism", published in The Spectator that year[2] and reprinted in The New York Times;[3] the word is a blend of the Latin res ("thing"), the French résister ("to resist"), and the existentialism school of philosophy.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistentialism


But this hinges more on superstition. The doctored "compass and map" of the example might spell real danger for the treasure-seeker.

this describes every household appliance - neat entry!


The objects were all monkeyed with.

monkey (with, about/around with) (v.)

Intransitive. colloquial (originally U.S.).   To play mischievous or foolish tricks. Also: to fool or mess about or around; to tinker,
tamper, or interfere (frequently with about with, around with, or
with).
1955 Any attempt to ‘monkey about’ with the powers or composition of the Upper House would destroy the balance of the
constitution.
Times 27 June 2/7
[OED online]


Tamper — usually used with with
Don't monkey with the settings
M-W


monkey with something—(*coll. also: monkey about with something) ... 2. (used showing disapproval) meddle with smth (making
unauthorized changes, etc): Somebody has been monkeying with it
before as the two bolts that hold the bar in place are missing.
Yuri
Dolgopolov; A Dictionary of Confusable Phrases (2016)



Someone had monkeyed around with the testing strips. Someone had
tried to kill me.
Cady Kalian; As Dead as It Gets (2007)


Could be a malfunction, but the last time this happened, we suspected
sabotage, if you'll recall. Couldn't prove it, but we all knew someone
had monkeyed with the damn thing.
Dave Foreman and ‎Bill Haywood;
Ecodefense: A Field Guide to Monkeywrenching (1987)


I think the OP is more interested in  the end result of the "monkeying with" process. I don't think they are looking for a verb here.
